# How to capture screenshot such that it would work with all display setups?

Tags: python, selenium, python-imaging-library

i want to capture screenshot and compare it with base image to check if they are equal. the below snippet works. but when i capture screenshot it is always of dimension 1544 * 638 (width * height)

Now my problem is if i am running my tests in a small device display and i capture screenshot then it would be some dimension the small device has.. and it might not match with my base image which is 1544 * 638.

How do i capture screenshot such that it is always of some small device display and what would be this dimension (meaning what could be the possible dimension) and how to do it. thanks.

```
    def capture_screenshot():
    canvas = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath")
    result = canvas_element.screenshot_as_png
    with open('compare_image.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
from selenium import webdriver
import io
from PIL import Image

def capture_screenshot():
    canvas = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath")
    image = canvas_element.screenshot_as_png
    imageStream = io.BytesIO(image)
    im = Image.open(imageStream)
    im.save(image_path)
```

Comment: it takes a screenshot of the element that you specify and saves it as png

Comment: but i want to have the screenshot dimensions to be changeable...in this case screenshot captured to the smallest screen size possible on which the tests could be run...what would be the idle size of screenshot such that it works on all test setups.